# no operator "<<" matches these operands -- operand types are: ostream << int(?)

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, matching

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    cout << 1 ;
    return 0;
}
```

My vs code still reports problem for this really simple code--"no operator "<<" matches these operands -- operand types are: ostream << int".

Comment: Can you post your intellisense configurations?

Comment: What command are you using to compile? Actually see above. Not clear if your problem is during compilation or during intellisense/indexing.

Comment: How and when exactly is this _reported_?

Answer (score 0):

[This `<<` implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) is not defined in `<iostream>`.

If you were using C++11 or newer, this would not matter, because `iostream` is now required to itself include `ostream`.

Before then, it wasn't. It may appear to work regardless under some implementations and in some configurations, due to some headers including other headers by pure chance. But regardless, at present your code is wrong, unless you're using C++11 or newer.

Also remember that IntelliSense and your "actual" compiler are typically two separate implementations, so there can be mismatches in support and settings there too.

The fix for C++03 would be to add:

```
#include <ostream>
```